# HTML5 on Eclipse PDT

Tags: eclipse, html, eclipse-pdt

I'm new to Eclipse, using PDT (helios). I keep getting warnings for "Unknown Tag (article)", also besides 'article' theres unknown tag warnings with 'nav', 'footer', 'header', etc. What I can infer from this is that Eclipse has a problem with HTML5 Validation.

I have one file Template.php which is used throughout the project and I've defined the DOCTYPE like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I tried looking into Project>Properties>Validation But I don't see anything there that I can change / modify for this. How would I ensure HTML5 is properly validated by eclipse?

Comment: How about try using Aptana Studio's HTML editor which seems to be able to understand HTML5?

Comment: Which version are you using?  Are you sure it's supposed to support HTML5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/142997/enable-html5-tags-on-eclipse).

Comment: @aaamos that question is from 18 months ago. Since then the HTML5 support was supposed to have been default.

Comment: True, but then, so is Helios. See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this blog post](http://www.habdas.org/2011/04/17/get-sideways-with-html5-in-eclipse/), HTML5 support was added to Eclipse Helios after its initial release. Have you made sure you've updated to the most recent version? If not, consider going straight to Indigo - since Eclipse doesn't require installation (just unzip and run), you can use multiple versions at the same time.